# ChromeDriver Notify by mail when have new release

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Does Chrome Driver have a Mailing list, that i can subcrise to have a notify when it have new version ?

Google Chrome is auto update, but which the Chrome Driver, i have to do it manually, so i need to have some notify when it have update, is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i write a custom script in linux, then using curl

```
curl -s https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE
```